Find the number of calendar quarters two dates span across in Excel
Could you help me with a formula that calculates the number of calendar quarters between two dates? I don't mean the regular =FLOOR(((YEAR(EndDate)*12+MONTH(EndDate))-(YEAR(StartDate)*12+MONTH(StartDate)))/3,1) but rather the number of calendar quarters those two dates will span across.
For example, if StartDate is 17 JUL 2023 and EndDate 9 JUL 2024:
From 17/07/2023 to 30/09/2023 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/10/2023 to 31/12/2023 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/01/2024 to 31/03/2024 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/04/2024 to 30/06/2024 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/07/2024 to 09/07/2024 - 1 calendar quarter

I've been pulling my hair but I can't seem to figure it out on my own. Thanks for you help!

Are you looking for =LET(dts,SEQUENCE(DATE(2024,7,9)-DATE(2023,7,17),1,DATE(2023,7,17)),UNIQUE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(dts)/3,0)&YEAR(dts)))?

Or just count of quarters =LET(dts,SEQUENCE(DATE(2024,7,9)-DATE(2023,7,17),1,DATE(2023,7,17)),ROWS(UNIQUE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(dts)/3,0)&YEAR(dts))))?

I would just use YEARFRAC =1+ROUNDUP(12*YEARFRAC(DATE(2023,10,1),DATE(2024,7,9),1)/3,0)

Should there be a +1 in the sequence? =LET(dts,SEQUENCE(DATE(2024,7,9)-DATE(2023,7,17)+1,1,DATE(2023,7,17)),ROWS(UNIQUE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(dts)/3,0)&YEAR(dts))))

My effort was =(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))*4+INT((MONTH(B1)-1)/3)-INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)+1 for what it's worth where A1 and B1 are the start and end dates.
